# Merging and ordering data using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects as such:

```
public class ExceptionFolderEntries
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
     
}
```

I am trying to get the next "Time" whether it be a starttime of endtime so that I can take action.
I know how to order the list using LINQ based on either StartTime OR EndTime but don't know how to merge the data and then sort the new merged list.

Example:
With the data:

> "ABC","1/1/2018 01:00", "1/2/2018 13:00"
>
> "MNO","1/1/2018 01:30", "1/1/2018 08:00"
>
> "XYZ","1/1/2018 09:00", "1/2/2018 13:00"

Would result in

> ABC 1/1 01:00
>
> MNO 1/1 01:30
>
> MNO 1/1 08:00
>
> XYZ 1/1 09:00
>
> ABC 1/2
> 13:00
>
> XYZ 1/2 13:00

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "merge" here. What are you merging with?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with test data and how it should ordered?

Comment: I suppose he means either `StartTime` or `EndTime` will be null and he wants to order on the one that has value

Comment: Is there a larger problem you're trying to solve? Because the solution that you're asking for will likely have to create twice as many items as your original list in order to display them like that. There may be a better solution depending on what the end goal is.

Comment: Of course there is a larger problem but the answers here help and will lead me to my goal.  In brief, I have a list of conditional data that can be effective over a time period.  I maintain the list in c# and pass it to c++ for interface to a realtime process that has to be very fast.  I pass the data that is relevant and have a scheduler look when the next "TIME" happens.  When it is 'time' I pass the info down in a format that can be easily absorbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make two `FolderEntries` new create collection one is for `StartTime`, another is for `EndTime`, then use linq `Concat` to combine two collections. then do `order by`

```
public class FolderEntries {
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FolderDateTime { get; set; }
}

var result =
  (from s1 in list select new FolderEntries(){
      Data = s1.Data,
      FolderDateTime = s1.StartTime
  }).Concat
  (from s2 in list select new FolderEntries {
      Data = s2.Data,
      FolderDateTime = s2.EndTime
  }).OrderBy(x=>x.FolderDateTime);
```

**Result**

```
ABC 1/1/2018 1:00:00 AM
MNO 1/1/2018 1:30:00 AM
XYZ 1/1/2018 9:00:00 AM
MNO 1/1/2018 1:08:00 PM
ABC 1/2/2018 1:00:00 PM
XYZ 1/2/2018 1:00:00 PM
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNIMTT)

Comment: What makes you think this is Folder datetime?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is perhaps too similar to Eriks answer, but one way to do it would be to select a new `ExceptionFolderEntries` (which should really be renamed `ExceptionFolderEntry` since it only represents a single item) for every non-null `StartTime` and `EndTime`, preserving whichever one we're reading (start or end) and leaving the other field `null`.

Then you can order that new (sizeable) list by the non-null value: `StartTime ?? EndTime`.

For example:

```
var sortedItems =
    // First select a new item for all non-null StartTimes
    items.Where(i => i.StartTime.HasValue) 
        .Select(i => new ExceptionFolderEntries {Data = i.Data, StartTime = i.StartTime})

        // Then concat with a new item for all non-null EndTimes
        .Concat(items
            .Where(i => i.EndTime.HasValue) 
            .Select(i => new ExceptionFolderEntries {Data = i.Data, EndTime = i.EndTime}))

        // And finally, order by the non-null field
        .OrderBy(i => i.StartTime ?? i.EndTime)
        .ToList();

// Now we can write out the data and the non-null field for each item
sortedItems.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine($"{i.Data} {i.StartTime ?? i.EndTime}"));
```

**Output**

[image]

In the sample above, `items` was initialized as:

```
var items = new List<ExceptionFolderEntries>
{
    new ExceptionFolderEntries
    {
        Data = "ABC",
        StartTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018 01:00"),
        EndTime = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2018 13:00")
    },
    new ExceptionFolderEntries
    {
        Data = "MNO",
        StartTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018 01:30"),
        EndTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018 08:00")
    },
    new ExceptionFolderEntries
    {
        Data = "XYZ",
        StartTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018 09:00"),
        EndTime = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2018 13:00")
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ExceptionFolderEntries[] entries = [];
entries.Select(e => new DateTime?[] {e.StartTime, e.EndTime).SelectMany(dt => dt).OrderBy(//ordery by logic)
```

First select out the datetimes into an array (creating you an array of arrays) then use select many to flatten it.

Edit: can also shorten too

```
ExceptionFolderEntries[] entries = [];
entries.SelectMany(e => new DateTime?[] {e.StartTime, e.EndTime).OrderBy(//ordery by logic)
```

Comment: @C Smith your code has some syntax errors. (like you typed ')' instead of '}'). Apart from that, this answers seems to fulfill Op's question. I don't understand why is it downvoted

Comment: yeah syntax wise i just quickly wrote it up in notepad, downvote wise.. no idea.

Comment: This only partially answers the question.  What's the sort logic look like?

Comment: OP does not ask for sort logic, he only wants to understand how to pull out the data he wants into a form that he can use his sort logic on.

Comment: *"don't know how to merge the data and then sort the new merged list"* I also read it that he was looking for sort logic as well, like: `"DontKnowHowTo(merge && sort)"`, rather than `"DontKnowHowTo(merge) && sort"`, but I also did not down-vote.

Comment: "I know how to order the list using LINQ based on either StartTime OR EndTime", kind of made me think he could sort it normally based on one property

Answer (score 0):

First off, your class should probably not end in an `(s)` because it's not a collection, so I'll be using `ExceptionFolderEntry` in my example.

I'd probably do something like:

```
class ExceptionFolderEntryMeta
{
  public ExceptionFolderEntry ExceptionFolderEntry { get; set; }
  public DateTime SortBy { get; set; }
  public bool IsStartTime { get; set; }
}

var exceptionFolderEntries = new List<ExceptionFolderEntry>();

var mergeList = exceptionFolderEntries 
  .Where(efe => efe.StartTime.HasValue)
  .Select(efe => new ExceptionFolderEntryMeta
    {
      ExceptionFolderEntry  = efe,
      SortBy = efe.StartTime,
      IsStartTime = true,
    })
  .Concat(exceptionFolderEntries 
    .Where(efe => efe.EndTime.HasValue)
    .Select(efe => new ExceptionFolderEntryMeta
      {
        ExceptionFolderEntry  = efe,
        SortBy = efe.EndTime,
        IsStartTime = false,
     }))
  .OrderBy(efem => efem.SortBy)
  .ToList())
```

I created the new class to allow correct sorting and to denote if it's a start time or end time (because you'll probably need to know that at some point).  I'm also taking into account that you've created those properties as nullable, so if one property is null, it only appears once and if both are null then it never appears.

Comment: You have a copy/paste error I believe - StartTime in the lower concat should be Endtime